# How is it that find_by_id, etc. work on an ActiveRecord array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, named-scope

Forgive me if I've got my terminology wrong; I am still quite new to Ruby *and* Rails.

For school I am working on an RoR project as part of a team. I was pair programming with a teammate, who actually happens to be experienced in RoR; and I wrote something like the following:

```
d = self.deliverables.find_all_by_lifecycle_id(self.lifecycle_id)
```

My pair programming partner stopped me at this point and explained that this wouldn't work, because `find_all_by_lifecycle_id` could only be resolved successfully if called by the `Deliverable` model, which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` (which is, in turn, the class responsible for providing such magical functionality). The `self.deliverables` method returns an *array*, which doesn't offer the same capabilities. The alternate solution he suggested was to use a **named scope**.

I protested: "But... I'm pretty sure I *tried* it already... and it *worked*."

Sure enough, it *does* seem to work, as we discovered when we tested it out just to humor me. What was my teammate missing? I certainly don't have the expertise to see what could've been wrong about what he said (it made sense to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it, `self.deliverables` is defined by `:has_many` association. In this case, it's not just a simple array. Some of the things you can do with such collection are highlighted in the [official rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference). In particular, check part *4.3.1.10 collection.find(…)*:
*The collection.find method finds objects within the collection. It uses the same syntax and options as ActiveRecord::Base.find.*

It doesn't mention `find_by_xxx` syntax explicitly, but like you I've found it works in practice.

Comment: `find_by_xxx` comes from the `method_missing` in `ActiveRecord::Base`, which is one of the ancestors of the `has_many` association object.

Comment: @Swanand I understand the technical side of the trick, I just wish there was some clear documentation about it. Not forcing me to determine the type of "has_many association object" at runtime and then check its sources.